# Remove all text before a character?

Tags: regex

I have a list of websites, and I would like to remove everything before the period and leave the domain left.

For example:

> google.com
>
> yahoo.net
>
> apple.org

Turned into this:

> .com
>
> .net
>
> .org

I have been tryhing this: `^.*?(?=.)` but it only grabs the first character before the period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not `^.*\.` and replace with `.` ?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Not sure why I didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 0):

if you only have the input you show then use : `\.[a-zA-Z]+`

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?(?=\.)
```

or

```
^.*?(?=\\.)
```

or

```
^.*?(?=[.])
```

You need to ``` escape the .``. ``` by default matches any character except newline.So you regex stop at the first character.